# using query.exec_ from PYQT5 to insert multiple values into QSqlDatabase

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqlquery, qsqldatabase

my table has 3 columns (1)id (2)firstname (3)lastname

My local variables have the following values

```
id = '1'

firstname = 'xxx'

lastname = 'yyy'
```

below query works and insert only value of id in the DB

```
query.exec_("insert into sportsmen (id)  values('%s')" %id)
```

How to extend the above query to insert all 3 values (id, firstname, lastname) in one go ?

Comment: use: `query.exec_("insert into sportsmen (id, firstname, lastname)  values('%s', '%s', '%s')" % (id, firstname, lastname)) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must execute the following command:

```
query.exec_("insert into sportsmen (id, firstname, lastname) values('%s', '%s', '%s')" % (id, firstname, lastname))
```